# NSUrlConnection in NSThread - No delegate is executed!

Tags: objective-c, url, connection, nsthread, delegation

I am using an NSURLConnection in an NSThread but none of the NSURLConnection's delegate methods are executed! I have a main method in my NSTread subclass and a while loop that keeps the thread active. Any help?

Sorry for all of this code but I think its the best way to describe my problem. So this is an object that does the async connection calling `createConnectionWithPath:userObjectReference`

```
@interface WSDAsyncURLConnection : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSDate *connectionTime;
    NSURLConnection *connection;

    id _theUserObject;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *connectionTime;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSURLConnection *connection;

- (void)createConnectionWithPath:(NSString *)thePath userObjectReference:(id)userObject;


@end


#import "WSDAsyncURLConnection.h"

@implementation WSDAsyncURLConnection
@synthesize connectionTime, receivedData, connection;


- (void) terminate
{
    if (self.connection) {
        [self.connection release];
        self.connection = nil;
    }
}   


- (void) createConnectionWithPath:(NSString *)thePath userObjectReference:(id)userObject;
{   
    _theUserObject = userObject;


    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thePath]
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];


    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (self.connection) 
    {
        /* record the start time of the connection */
        self.connectionTime = [NSDate date];

        /* create an object to hold the received data */
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    } 
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];   
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    /* appends the new data to the received data */ 
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{    
    [self terminate];
}


- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // displays the elapsed time in milliseconds
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.connectionTime];
    // displayes the length of data received
    NSUInteger length = [self.receivedData length];

    NSString* aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];   

    [self terminate];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:WSDAsynchURLConnectionDidFinished
                                                        object:_theUserObject 
                                                      userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aStr forKey:@"urlResponseString"]];

    NSLog(@"ti=%f, l=%d, response=%@", elapsedTime, length, aStr);

}

@end
```

This code is mostly from an apple's example project and it works fine outside an NSThread.
But when I use it in the following thread subclass no delegate method is executed !!

```
@implementation IncomingThread



- (void) main {

    NSAutoreleasePool *poool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];


// I start the URLConnection here ... But no delegate is executed !
        [urlConn createConnectionWithPath:@"http://localhost:8888" userObjectReference:nil];


    while (![self isCancelled]) {

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.];
    }


    [poool release];

}


- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

        urlConn = [[WSDAsyncURLConnection alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) dealloc {

    NSLog(@"deallocating (%@)...", [self className]);


    [urlConn release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: you don't need to use NSURLConnection in the separate thread. Since it is asynchronous it doesn't block the main thread.
Second: there is not processing of your connection because you always stop the execution of the thread's runloop with this peace of code:

```
 while (![self isCancelled]) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.];
    }
```

From the docs for the `sleepForTimeInterval`:

```
No run loop processing occurs while the thread is blocked.
```

Comment: xmmm... Even if I comment `sleepForTimeInterval` still no delegates call occur. (I don't release the thread - except if it is released on its own when `main` method finishes but no!)

Comment: Yep, of course, cause the thread exits immediately. If you want to use separate thread then use synchronous request or do async one in the main thread.

Comment: "use synchronous request or do async one in the main thread" logical And solved my issue. Both ways worked Fine. (Async request on a thread is indeed !! noisy !!). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You’re doing this the hard way. `NSURLConnection` does not play very nice with threads, since it needs a run loop to work. Your thread does not have a run loop and therefore the code does not work. Why not run the connection on the main thread? Or you can wrap the connection in an `NSOperation`, [sample code here](https://gist.github.com/578636). And nowadays you also have the option to use a synchronous connection and dispatch it to a global GCD queue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look to the sample code NSOperation

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to assign the delegate?

Something like:

```
self.connection.delegate = self;
```

Just because your class `WSDAsyncURLConnection` implements the delegate methods, doesn't mean they are being called.

Comment: But of course -> `self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest **delegate:self** startImmediately:YES];` in the code above. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Late but it may save others life :)

Solution link is : NSURLConnection delege methods does not work